# Button with onclick

Tags: javascript, php

I have an error when I want to click on the add button inside a table to create a row.

Below the js errorand summary code.
if it's not enough, let me know.

tk

javascript error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addOptionValueDownloadFilename is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

code

```
   $content .= '<td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="addOptionValueDownloadFilename(' . $i . ');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . $this->app->getDef('button_insert') . '" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td> ';
....

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  var option_value_row = {$n};
  var tableid = $(this).data('tableid');
  var modeB2B_B2C = {$mode_B2B_B2C};

  function addOptionValueDownloadFilename(option_row) {....
    .....
    $('#option-value' + option_row + ' tbody').append(html);
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();

      option_value_row++;
    }
//--></script>
```